# Custom Class "unrecognised selector send to instance"

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

#### Backstory

Im currently creating an custom class that handles/mimics the look of the Facebook menu app,
i have created this functionality in a separate project (working) and thought it would be a good idea to make the code reusable.

#### The problem

I'm getting an "unrecognised selector sent to instance" error, while i'm really certain i have implemented the method "handle" i cannot figure out what goes wrong. if anyone would be kind enough to help me. or push me in the right direction

#### Edit

The full error generated by my output window

> 2013-03-06 19:56:39.520 SwipeMenuProject[14347:c07] -[__NSArrayM handle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7558310

#### The Code

> UISwipeMenuControl.m

```c
#import "UISwipeMenuControl.h"

@implementation UISwipeMenuControl

@synthesize frontWindow = _frontWindow, backWindow = _backWindow, navController = _navController, btnHandle = _btnHandle;

-(id)init
{
    self.frontWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.backWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-61,0,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)];

    self.btnHandle = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [self.btnHandle setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 20)];
    [self.btnHandle setTitle:@"Handle" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer * dragGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handle:)];
    [self.btnHandle addGestureRecognizer:dragGesture];

    UIViewController * viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [viewController setTitle:@"Swipe Menu"];
    [viewController.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.btnHandle]];

    self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    [self.frontWindow setRootViewController:self.navController];

    return self;
}

-(UIWindow *)getFrontWindow
{
    return self.frontWindow;
}

-(UIWindow *)getBackWindow
{
    return self.backWindow;
}

-(UINavigationController *)getNavigationController
{
    return self.navController;
}

-(void) setRootViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    [viewController.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.btnHandle]];
    [self.frontWindow setRootViewController:self.navController];
}
-(void)handle:(id)sender
{
    //unrelated code here
}
```

> Appdelegate.m

```c
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UISwipeMenuControl * swipeMenu = [[UISwipeMenuControl alloc] init];

    CustomViewController * cViewController = [[CustomViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [swipeMenu setRootViewController:cViewController];

    self.window = [swipeMenu getFrontWindow];
    [self.window setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Post the entire error message. You left out the important part of the message.

Comment: This is the exact error im seeing in my console >    2013-03-06 19:56:39.520 SwipeMenuProject[14347:c07] -[__NSArrayM handle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7558310

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is an ownership/memory issue. `UISwipeMenuControl` seems to be deallocated when the recognizer sends its action.

Enable zombies to investigate if that's the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your input this was indeed the problem !